# JQuery mobile IOS device how to remove default scroll on web

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I am having issues with the default "refresh" scrollbar in IOS. I have created my own scrollbar in a div and i cant seem to access it without using the default scrollbar in IOS. I have fixed the problem on both web and android but i cant seem to figure out how to remove the "default" scrollbar on IOS devices (phone and Ipad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent user from scrolling the screen you need to redefine touch move event

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried to input your code in my program however i get the same problem. I have tried switching browser to chrome and firefox instead of safari but nothing seems to work. It seems like there is an obstacle in IOS that i cant seem to handle. I cant bypass the IOS default scrolling. Any other suggestions? thx